# Java | manually change a value in the properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

So I have a .properties file in java. One of the properties hold the value for a certain path which happened to change.

What I did is edit the .properties file to change the value to the new path. However it seems that I am always reading the old value.

What could be the reason for that ?

**EDIT**
This is how I read the properties file

`propertiesFilePath = "configs/index.properties";
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(propertiesFilePath);
properties.load(input);`

Comment: When running you application are you explicitly providing this properties file in classpath?

Comment: If you're doing Java web stuff, did you make sure that the new properties file got deployed?

Comment: How are you reading properties file ?

Comment: The file you have edited is not the one that is used to read the properties from.

Comment: @SanketD .. I edit my question to explain how I read the properties file

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, not web stuff .. it is a local java code

Comment: @Henry I provide the path to the properties file .. as I am just running a local java code (not a jar file) I can't see how can I provide an invalid properties path

Comment: We can go on and guess more reasons why this happens ("you forgot to save the edited file" and "the property value is not used because it is later overwritten with a hard coded value" are two of them) or you find out more with a debugger.

Comment: @Henry well thanks for the suggestion, it actually helped. Since I did not wrote this code from the scratch I was missing some details in the reading process .. it was reading from a different property file .. thanks

Comment: [`properties.load(input);`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Properties.java#Properties.load%28java.io.InputStream%29) actually reads content and puts into memory. change made physically on disk won't reflect. you will have to re-read it to get the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two reason for this.

1. You have multiple `index.properties` present and you are updating the properties in wrong file. Also ensure you don't have multiple entries for same property.
2. After updating your .properties file, you are not restarting your application. You should restart to have it read the updated properties or you have to explicitly have functionality in your code to load it when there is change in his file(this is also do able).